# If $e^{a_n} \to \infty$ then $a_n$ goes to infinity

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{ a_n} = \infty$. Then it is clear that $a_n$ better go to infinity.

Do we require that $a_n$ be increasing? I think it is not required since $e^x$ goes to inifnity only when $x \to \infty$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b_n=e^{a_n}$. Then $a_n= \ln (b_n)$. If $b_n \to \infty$, then $a_n \to \infty$.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it **if** you already know that if $x_n\to\infty$, then $\ln(x_n)\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $a_n$ does not need to be increasing.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need $a_n$ to be increasing. For example, you could have

$$a_n=\begin{cases}n^2 & \text{ if }n\text{ is even}\\
  n & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$